# Converting JPEG/PNG to Shapefile?

Tags: python, r

Suppose I have the following image (Toronto, Canada) saved as a JPEG or a PNG:

[image]

**My Question:** Suppose I provided the region of the world and some longitude and latitude coordinates around this picture for reference.

Using software such as R or Python - are there any techniques that can be used to identify the perimeter of this red shape? E.g. Identify a JSON list of geographical coordinates - essentially turning this into a shapefile?

Thanks!

Comment: You can manually georeference the raster and digitize the shape. But that will be alot of work if you got many rasters.

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems here: 1. georeferencing the image so things have the right world coordinates, and 2. raster to vector conversion.

1. is fairly easy, given a small number of known coordinates on the map (eg two opposite corners) you can create a "world" file and then its a spatial image file and GDAL can put it on the map for you. You will need to know what coordinate system the raster is based on though - for example the cells might be EPSG 3857 and the coordinates in lat-long, then you have to convert the coords to 3857 for the world file. Search "GDAL world file" for more.
2. Is harder. If you have a clean image with just a coloured line and a single colour background then raster-vector conversion is much easier than when you have a cluttered background and a line feature obscured by other art such as labels and markers. Also it looks like your line is dotted linework which will be even harder to join up. You could do some simple image processing and find all pixels above some red threshold, because there's not much red anywhere else (note white cells are a mix of red, blue and green so you really need to threshold on low blue and green channels). Once you've got the pixel coords then join them nearest-neighbour-wise to create a line. Alternatively once its georeferenced you can load it into a GIS and trace it by hand as a new vector layer.

Or you can try and find a source of these boundaries that isn't straight off a Google Maps screengrab, which might well be against the terms and conditions of use of Google Maps. Either postal code boundaries are freely available in vector form, in which case get them from there, or Google have paid to have them on their maps, in which case you may be in violation of Ts+Cs by tracing them in any manner.